# What does get_rect() do in the following program? Why was it used?

Tags: python, pygame

I was going through a tutorial here - www.raywenderlich.com/24252/beginning-game-programming-for-teens-with-python. In Step 4, he used the following statement :

```
# 6.1 - Set player position and rotation
position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
angle = math.atan2(position[1]-(playerpos[1]+32),position[0]-(playerpos[0]+26))
playerrot = pygame.transform.rotate(player, 360-angle*57.29)
playerpos1 = (playerpos[0]-playerrot.get_rect().width/2, playerpos[1]-playerrot.get_rect().height/2)
screen.blit(playerrot, playerpos1)
```

what exactly did he do? and why did he do so?

Comment: In the **pygame** docs you can read the description of `Surface.get_rect`: _get the rectangular area of the Surface_ (see [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect)).

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy, run and test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates that you pass to [`pygame.Surface.blit`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) are the coords of the top left corner. I think the `playerpos` in Step 4 should be the center position of the image/surface, so you need to subtract the half width and the half height of the surface to get the top left coords (where you want to blit it). The author uses the [`pygame.Surface.get_rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) method to get a [rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) with the width and height of the rotated surface, but he could use the [`pygame.Surface.get_width`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_width) and `.get_height` methods as well.

After each rotation, the `playerrot` surface will have a different size, so you need to call the `get_rect` method again to get a new rect with the updated width and height which you need to adjust the coordinates.

---

By the way, it looks like adding `32` and `26` in this line causes problems with the rotation.

```
angle = math.atan2(position[1]-(playerpos[1]+32),position[0]-(playerpos[0]+26))
```

This should work correctly:

```
angle = math.atan2(position[1]-playerpos[1], position[0]-playerpos[0])
```

---

It's also possible to use a `pygame.Rect` as the blit position, so you could do this to create a rect with the size of the rotated surface and the `playerpos` as the `center` coordinates:

```
playerpos1 = playerrot.get_rect(center=playerpos)
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, I didn't add the 32 and 26 in my code either, since I never understood why the author did that.

Answer (score 0):

I think get_rect() is a method to get the rectangle object and then he's getting its width property to calculate the position on next player. I guess this method is defined somewhere in the code. Maybe see rest of the code too.

Answer (score 0):

He's using it as a means to calculate the movement of the bunny that occurs from being rotated, by getting the rectangle for the bunny image and splitting it in half to get the (x, y) changes in position for the bunny:

```
------                                        ---------
|X   |    ---->  Rotate 90 degrees   ---->    |      X|
|    |                                        |       |
------                                        ---------
```